# IntelliJ suppress warnings for unchanged lines

Tags: java, intellij-idea

is it possible to suppress all warnings in IntelliJ for all unchanged lines? I am working in a project with java files larger than 2000 lines and there are warnings everywhere. To get a better overview of my  code I want to only inspect my changed or added lines.

Comment: You change can cause warning in unchanged line. What should happened then?

Comment: Could be displayed as well

Comment: I think this impossible. Because warnings does not have single cause. Most of the time line that you changed can be changed the way that any warning disappear. Which mean that you get all warning back.

Comment: I suggest either switch warning off, either fix them (not all at one time, but one by one every time you change something in this file)

Comment: It would be nice to be able to fix all, but there are just too many. Also the other developers keep track of the changes, and they don't want to see such changes (only if the functionality changed, too)

Comment: You should talk with other developer and ask them what do they think about it. Maybe they ok with warnings. looks like it true because warning exists and nobody do anything about it. In this case you can try to convince them to change they're mind. Or turn off warning (I put a bet on later :) )

Comment: There are too many developers to talk to all of them :/
I'll just leave the warnings on and hope I don't oversee a warning coded by myself^^

Answer (score 0):

Summary from comment conversation:

Bad luck. Turning warnings off is the only solution (no one care about them anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this. However, going forward you can use the annotation @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" ) to suppress warnings that you do not care about. This does nothing for existing code unless you apply it to each warning (not what I would recommend), but will achieve the desired effect going forward.